# Unable to read value from input box

Tags: powershell

I have powershell code where user enters text into an input box, but when I attempt to write this output to screen, it is blank

```
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "Data Entry Form"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
    {$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$OKButton.Text = "OK"
$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Please enter the information in the space below:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objTextBox) 

$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

write-host "x is $x"
```

The output to console is

```
x is
```

I thought that

```
$OKButton.Add_Click({$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
```

Would read the input into $x if the "OK" button was clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running into a problem with the Scope of your variable $x.  Scope inheritance flows downhill only by default, not uphill.  The script block in your $OKButton.Add_Click line is a child scope of the script and any variable changes inside that scope are not written up to the parent scope.

Here's a [better description](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2007/04/14/controlling-the-scope-of-variables.aspx) than I could write.

I've run into this in the past and one possible solution is to declare your $x variable earlier in your script so that it is created in the "Script" scope and then specifically reference that script scope variable in your $OKButton.Add_Click line with **$script:x=$objTextBox.Text**

Note the differences of output in these two simple one-liners that display the difference in the scope.  **$Local:A** is the child $A variable inside the local scope of the script block and **$script:A** is the parent $A variable in the entire script scope:

```
$A = "Yes" ; $A ; &{$local:A = "No" ; $A} ; $A
Yes
No
Yes

$A = "Yes" ; $A ; &{$script:A = "No" ; $A} ; $A
Yes
No
No
```

EDIT:  I had a chance to test this and simply stating that the $x variable should be in the script scope is fine, you don't have to declare it earlier as I mentioned before.  This should work fine:

```
$OKButton.Add_Click({$script:x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this by replacing

```
{$x=$objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
```

with

```
{Write-Host "x is" $objTextBox.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
```

In the scenario you present, it should do the same thing.